# Show that $\frac{(2k+h)^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2k+h)^n}{(n+2)!} \rightarrow 0$ as $(h,k)\rightarrow 0.$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

To do this, I need to show two things:

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{(2k+h)^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}& = & 0 \quad &(1)&\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2k+h)^n}{(n+2)!}& = & \text{Bounded} \quad &(2)&\\
\end{array}
$$

(1) is not hard once I go over to polar coordinates. But how can I show (2)? Will the ratiotest suffice?

$$\left| \frac{(2k+h)^{n+1}}{((n+1)+2)!}\cdot\frac{(n+2)!}{(2k+h)^n} \right|=\left| \frac{2k+h}{n} \right|\rightarrow0, \ \text{as} \ n\rightarrow\infty.$$

But this only means that the series is absolutely convergent for constant $h,k$. In my limit $(h,k)$ tends to the origin.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ratio test is ok, as an alternative note simply that that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2k+h)^n}{(n+2)!}$ converges absolutely by comparison test with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+2)!}$ indeed

$$\frac{\frac{ |2k+h|^n }{(n+2)!}}{\frac{1}{(n+2)!}}=|2k+h|^n\to0$$

Comment: isn't it $-n$:th power?

Comment: why negative? it is a ratio $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ for the two series.

Comment: But why doesn't my ratiotest work?

Comment: @Parseval yes it is ok laso by ratio test! You need only to correct a typo $$\left| \frac{2k+h}{n+1} \right|\to0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2k+h)^n}{(n+2)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(n+2)!}=\frac 1{x^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}$$

Now, think about the expansion od $e^x$.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Well I get that $$\frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}=\frac{1}{x^2}(e^x-x-1)=e^{2k+h}-\frac{1}{2k+h}+\frac{1}{(2k+h)^2}.$$

It's division by zero as $(h,k)$ approaches $(0,0)$.